# How to get customer id from a charge response of stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to get customer_id of a stripe customer from the response of of charge entity. But response is not providing the customer id in return.

```
&stripe.Charge JSON: {
  "id": "ch_1AxWbTFytruJp2FXW6iuRd1X",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 100,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_17JOXKFytruJp2FXS4XNisQd",
  "captured": false,
  "created": 1504339423,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
  "destination": null,
  "dispute": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "fraud_details": {
  },
  "invoice": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "order": null,
  "outcome": null,
  "paid": true,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "refunded": false,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1AxWbTFytruJp2FXW6iuRd1X/refunds"
  },
  "review": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": {
    "id": "card_1AxWPmFytruJp2FXw4m0V0fN",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": "10001",
    "address_zip_check": "unchecked",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "customer": null,
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 4,
    "exp_year": 2024,
    "fingerprint": "sNtyd9sZ2vA6o4IM",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": "Mandeep",
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "source_transfer": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

But it has a customer field inside the object which is null. Can anyone please tell me why am I getting this null?

What I am trying to do is to make a system where customer can book anonymously on site and while creating the booking the customer gets registered and charged for the total amount of the booking. I need to keep track of the customer's stripe account id and card id. So the problem is if I am creating a customer then I am not able to get its card id but when I am charging the customer then I am not able to get the customer id.

Customer Response:

```
&stripe.Customer JSON: {
  "id": "cus_BKAxGZre2HCNIU",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1504339424,
  "currency": "usd",
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_BKAxGZre2HCNIU/sources"
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_BKAxGZre2HCNIU/subscriptions"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `charge` using only the credit card token, no Stripe customer is created, you only create a payment with no associated customer.
So it's normal that you the API returns `customer: null`.

Instead of charging a credit card, I think you should **charge a new customer**.
In your backend code, you could handle the payment in 2 steps:

- STEP 1: create a new customer, passing the credit card token to store
  the customer's card
- STEP 2: charge the customer, using the customer    ID returned by
  STEP 1 API call.

Doing this, you charge the customer with the credit card that is stored in customer's data.

For more details, check here: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart#saving-card-information

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can access card_id while creating new customer using following code (in Golang):

```
for _, data := range customer.Sources.Values{
        card_id = data.ID
    }

    fmt.Println(card_id)
```

I spend almost 1 day to figure it out. Actually in customer structure(under stripe package) there are some fields which are having embedded types and such fields are further connected to some other structure in different files. So there is hierarchy to access structure fields like above.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks!